# Why Django Rest Framework 404 after browsable API login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when I try to login using the Rest Framework browsable API, I get a 404 after the login and the URL points to /accounts/profile.

Comment: can you paste your django rest settings ?

Comment: and root `urls.py`

Comment: you can change the login redirect url from your `settings.py` by addlng `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "some_custom_url"`

Comment: also maybe you don't have the rest_framework index url added to your my_app/urls.py